# $L_p([1,\infty],\mu)$ isn't contained in $L_q([1,\infty],\mu)$ where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to find functions which are integrable on one side but not integrable for the other side. Suppose we have $q > p$. Then Consider the function $f(x) = 1/x^{1/p}$ then $f(x)^p = 1/x$. Then we have $f(x) \notin L_p([1,\infty],\mu)$, but $f(x)^q \in L_q([1,\infty],\mu)$.

I want to construct an element in $L_p([1,\infty],\mu)$ that is not an element of $L_q([1,\infty],\mu)$. Any suggestions?

Comment: $(x-1)^{-1/2}$ is in $L^1(1,2)$ but not in $L^2(1,2)$.

Comment: why is that ? What about general p and q when we have p < q ? Can you please include the details and for general p and q ?

Comment: I assume that you can compute basic integrals. From my example you can easily construct what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^n \chi_{(n, n+2^{-2n})}(x).$$

We have
$$\|f\|_1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^n \cdot 2^{-2n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} = 1 < \infty,$$
but
$$\|f\|_2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2^n)^2 \cdot 2^{-2n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1 = \infty.$$

Thus, $f$ satisfies your request with $p=1$ and $q=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Choose $f(x) = (x-1)^{-1/q}$ for $x\in (1,2)$ and $f(x) = 0$ on $[2,\infty)$.